# How realign existing contents of buffer on column-width?

Tags: fill-paragraph, auto-fill-mode

I added the following settings to my `dot-Emacs`:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
        (lambda() (set-fill-column 80)))
```

When I'm typing sentences in an existing Org-file  which are longer than 80 columns, it places on the next line in the Org-file. It works fine.

However, I have in the same Org-file already sentences that I typed in the past,
which are longer than 80 columns.

How could I tell Emacs that he must format all sentences in the buffer which are longer than 80 columns. So that the existing words, which exceed 80 columns-limit will begin on the next line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind filling *paragraphs* rather than just individual
sentences, the simplest way to do it is probably to select the
entire buffer and use `fill-region`.  Here's a simple command that
will automate the process:

```
(defun fill-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (widen)
      (fill-region (point-min) (point-max)))))
```

Comment: Simple, and such clever. Dan, you still manage to amaze me with such commands that I would spent many hours looking up and I could never worked out then.

Comment: @ReneFroger: thanks.  As you get more experience working with elisp, some of these things will become like second nature.  Never stop learning!